# Placing buttons next to each other

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to place the buttons next to each other. For example below code places it below each other.
Can we place it next to each other with a gap?
Is there a way to achieve this?

```css
.act_button span {
  color: black;
  width: 10vh;
}

.act_button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  place-content: space-between;
}

.act_button>span {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: -2vh;
  margin-right: -1vh;
}
```

```html
<button class="act_button" type="button">
  <span>Top left</span>
  <span>Top right</span>
  <span>Bottom left</span>
  <span>Bottom right</span>
</button>

<button class="act_button" type="button">
  <span>Top left</span>
  <span>Top right</span>
  <span>Bottom left</span>
  <span>Bottom right</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of `flexbox`. You can wrap your two buttons inside a `div` and then set that to `display: flex;` - this will get them to show next to each other.

[Read more on Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```css
.act_button span {
  color: black;
  width: 10vh;
}
.act_button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  place-content: space-between;
}

.act_button>span {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: -2vh;
  margin-right: -1vh;
}

.button-wrapper {
  display:flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="act_button" type="button">
    <span>Top left</span>
    <span>Top right</span>
    <span>Bottom left</span>
    <span>Bottom right</span>
  </button>
  
   <button class="act_button" type="button">
      <span>Top left</span>
      <span>Top right</span>
      <span>Bottom left</span>
      <span>Bottom right</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: He also asked for a gap so you should use the `gap`-property aswell

Comment: Great thanks. How can add a gap here?

Comment: @manup I've edited my answer. As Tacoshy said, just use `gap`

Comment: `.button-wrapper { gap: value; }` it adds the gap as you define as value.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your buttons in a container and add display:flex; to the container CSS. Maybe something like this?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.act_button span {
  color: black;
  width: 10vh;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
}
.act_button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  place-content: space-between;
}

.act_button>span {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: -2vh;
  margin-right: -1vh;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <button class="act_button" type="button">
    <span>Top left</span>
    <span>Top right</span>
    <span>Bottom left</span>
    <span>Bottom right</span>
  </button>
  
   <button class="act_button" type="button">
    <span>Top left</span>
    <span>Top right</span>
    <span>Bottom left</span>
    <span>Bottom right</span>
  </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can wrap your two buttons with a div. The use css style in div with class like  then style the class like: display:flex;
margin right:20px; (that you need)
or more style you can apply

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).